# Getting Read time out when connecting to hive/spark sql through squirrel sql

Tags: jdbc, apache-spark-sql, squirrel-sql

I'm trying to use Squirrel SQL to connect to spark-sql thriftserver using jdbc.
For smaller resultset I'm getting the response. But for queries which are running for more than 30s, Squirrel throws the below exception:

```
Error: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException:
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
SQLState: 08S01
ErrorCode: 0
```

But when I check spark job page on port 4040 it shows that the query execution is successful. Even when I run the same query thru beeline I'm able to see the results. Looks like there is a client side timeout for squirrel sql. Kindly let me know how to increase the timeout parameter.

Comment: Did you ever find the answer for this? Having the same problem

Comment: Not found the solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

Go to File -> Global Preferences -> SQL Tab -> Change "Login Timeout" to 0 -> Press OK

After that reconnect the session by  Session -> Reconnect

I think this works because of this bug. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-14517